# In angular is preloadingStrategy async by default?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Implementation of preload strategy -

```
...

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'welcome',
    component: 'WelcomeComponent'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { preload: true },
    loadChildren: '@app/post-login/post-login.module#PostLoginModule'
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
...
...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: SelectiveStrategy })
...
```

In the above code, we are lazy loading PostLoginModule on /home path. Also we are implementing a custom preload strategy. (Similar to the one in the angular guide).

Implementation of SelectiveStrategy :

```
...
@Injectable()
export class SelectiveStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      return load();
    }
    return of(null);
  }
}
```

In SelectiveStrategy, we check for `route.data.preload`. If it is set to true, then we call `load()`. Else return `of(null)`.

In the above implementation, is the PostLoginModule loaded on the initial page load? Or is it loaded sometime after the initial page load asynchronously in the background?

The angular guide is not very clear on this. I saw few blogs saying that it will be asynchronously loaded in the background after the initial page load. But is it mentioned somewhere in the angular documentation?

Comment: It is loaded asynchronlously. From https://angular.io/guide/router#preloading-background-loading-of-feature-areas: *Ideally, the app would launch with just the AppModule and the HeroesModule loaded and then, almost immediately, load the CrisisCenterModule in the background. By the time the user navigates to the Crisis Center, its module will have been loaded and ready to go.

That's preloading.* From https://angular.io/guide/router#custom-preloading-strategy: *The router calls the preload method with two arguments:[...] A loader function that can load the routed module asynchronously.*

Comment: thanks for explanation and the links @JBNizet